# Checking Display Value of HTML element and saving to a Cookie in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am currently trying to use jQuery to toggle the appearance of a `shoutbox` and remember the state (hidden / visible) from page to page. The problem I am having is in getting a cookie set to remember the state.

The code I have so far is below, but it doesn't seem to be executing the `if` statement correctly. Any ideas why?

```
function show_shoutbox() {
    $('#SB').toggle("fast"); 

    if ($('#SB').css('display') == "none") { 
        document.cookie = "displaysb=false;";
    } else { 
        document.cookie = "displaysb=true; ";
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery - so I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious. I'm hoping to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ( $('#SB').is(':visible') ) {
    ...
}
```

It's normalized to work a little better than checking `display`.

Comment: It's not really a matter of that working or not. That's the code to check to see if an element is visible with jQuery. Voting down answers because your code is broken hardly seems intuitive or helpful. "it doesn't seem to be executing the if statement correctly" - I succinctly described to you how to do this. Please rephrase your question if you don't like getting answers to the one you asked.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't me who downvoted... any case, I did test your code with alert boxes, and it always told me it was visible, whether it actually was or not.

Comment: You should probably submit a bug to jQuery along with a test case http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible as you seem to have found a bug, then.

Answer (score 0):

document.cookie doesn't work that way. Check out:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

It even has code at the end of it:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what I'm doing wrong? While the code is helpful, I want to know *why* something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use `$('#SB')[0]` instead of `$('#SB')`.
this part of code returns an array of all elements that satisfy the requirements. 
and if you only have one element with this ID, the first element with the index `0` is the element you are searching for.

Answer (score -3):

Cache your element for efficiency

```
var sb=$('#SB');//cache once outside the function
function show_shoutbox() {
  sb.toggle("fast"); 
  if ( sb.is(':visible')) {//do your business
  }
  else { //do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.