# Loading HTML content into DIV

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to load a HTML file into a DIV and access that whenever i need.
This should be done once when loading the script and i can access this no.of 
time in my code. The HTML contains lots of divs in it and i want to get
particular div from the loaded content.
Here is my code
$("#contentdiv").load("message.html #divname");

can u tell me how to get rid from this

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: shaik, what do you want to get rid of?

Comment: i answered some similar problem [here][1]
check it out ;)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955437/checking-display-value-of-html-element-and-saving-to-a-cookie-in-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

Load the page, when loaded, get the div you want, and insert it into your `contentdiv`.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'message.html', 
         success : function(data) { 
                       $('#contentdiv').html($(data).find('#divname')); 
                    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("#contentdiv").html($(message.html).find("#divname"));
```

Comment: I thought the aim was to extract a particular div from the the html response. i.e. $(message.html).find("#divname")...

Comment: yeah, `load ("url #divname")` is a shortcut for that

Answer (score -1):

From your question I understood that u want to select a particular div from the response html which will be loaded on `#contentdiv`.

Its better to access $('#contentdiv->ur div name').html();
or $('#contentdic .div').html() . here .div is a css class

Comment: @Pekka:i mean that after loading if u want to put some thing in a div inside the loaded div.we need to give this way. That I was told here

Comment: yeah, but `load("url #divname")` is already a shortcut for that.

Comment: $load("url #divname")-> loads the html(). If the html contains a div say class=foo, then $(#divname foo).html() .. Just selecting the particular div. html() is just an example.